# How to improve search speed in data grid view

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, datagridview

I have a datagridview which contain student details (first name, last name, gender, degree and burn date)

I write this code to perform "keyboard search" (for this example I "load" the data locally):

```
    public class StudentDetails
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public string gender;
        public string degree;
        public DateTime burnDate;
    };

    public List<StudentDetails> studentSearchList = new List<StudentDetails>();    // Contain all dgv for searches

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshDataGridView();
    }

    private void refreshDataGridView()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            StudentDetails sd = new StudentDetails();
            sd.firstName = GetRandomFirstName();
            sd.lastName = GetRandomLastName();
            sd.gender = GetRandomGender();
            sd.degree = GetRandomDegree();
            sd.burnDate = GetRandomBurnDate();
            studentSearchList.Add(sd);
            addRowToDataGrid(sd);
        }
    }

    bool detailsContain(StudentDetails sd, string s)
    {
        if (sd.firstName.ToLower().Contains(s) ||
            sd.lastName.ToLower().Contains(s) ||
            sd.gender.ToLower().Contains(s) ||
            sd.degree.ToLower().Contains(s) ||
            sd.burnDate.ToShortDateString().ToString().Contains(s))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void addRowToDataGrid(StudentDetails sd)
    {
        string[] row = new string[] { sd.firstName, sd.lastName, sd.gender, sd.degree, sd.burnDate.ToShortDateString().ToString() };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<StudentDetails> list_SD = new List<StudentDetails>();
        String s = textBox1.Text;
        s = s.ToLower().Trim();

        foreach (StudentDetails sd in studentSearchList)
            if (detailsContain(sd, s)) list_SD.Add(sd);

        // Clear old rows
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        // Adding the new rows
        foreach (StudentDetails sd in list_SD)
            addRowToDataGrid(sd);

    }
```

My problem is the searching is too slowly and I have no idea to improve the speed.
I tried to declare another list that contain all database and to fill studentSearchList just with the last search result until the user press on delete character but it's not so help and it's cost memory…

Maybe someone have good search algorithm to suggest ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your records "StudentDetails" in the array, not in the list.
Thereafter, build additional index-array (unsigned int or short) 
for each searchable field, and sort indices in those arrays according values
of appropriate fields.
  Thereafter, you will just use binary search for each necessary field, which is log(N).

Comment: Thank you! I understand your point, anyway I'll be glad if you have a link for any example.

Answer (score 0):

You should first measure what takes time. Is it the search itself (I doubt) or refreshing the datagrid on every keystroke ?

Comment: The search spent the time